# ThrottleRequestMiddleware for api route in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, routes, rate-limiting

I have built api routes for returning posts as json resource, when I am putting the middleware 'apiThrottle:5,1' on an api route it just display the result for two times and then in the third one it will generate json response 'Too many attempts...'

But when I add the middleware to a web route it will keep showing the results for the maximium number of times (which is in this case is 5) and after that it generates 'Too many attempts...'

Web route: `https://project.test/`

```
Route::middleware('apiThrottle:5,1')->get('/', function (){
     return 'Web Route';
});
```

Api route: `https://project.test/api/`

```
Route::middleware('apiThrottle:5,1')->get('/', function (){
     return 'API Route';
});
```

Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests;

class ThrottleRequestsMiddleware extends ThrottleRequests
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @param  int $maxAttempts
     * @param  int $decayMinutes
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $maxAttempts = 60, $decayMinutes = 1)
    {
        $key = $this->resolveRequestSignature($request);

        $maxAttempts = $this->resolveMaxAttempts($request, $maxAttempts);

        if ($this->limiter->tooManyAttempts($key, $maxAttempts)) {
            return $this->buildJsonResponse($key, $maxAttempts);
        }

        $this->limiter->hit($key, $decayMinutes);

        $response = $next($request);

        return $this->addHeaders(
            $response, $maxAttempts,
            $this->calculateRemainingAttempts($key, $maxAttempts)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Create a 'too many attempts' JSON response.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  int  $maxAttempts
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function buildJsonResponse($key, $maxAttempts)
    {
        $response = new JsonResponse([
            'error' => [
                'code' => 429,
                'message' => 'Too many attempts, please slow down the request.',
            ],
        ], 429);

        $retryAfter = $this->limiter->availableIn($key);

        return $this->addHeaders(
            $response, $maxAttempts,
            $this->calculateRemainingAttempts($key, $maxAttempts, $retryAfter),
            $retryAfter
        );
    }
}
```

`Kernel.php`:

```
     /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        .
        .
        .
        'apiThrottle' => \App\Http\Middleware\ThrottleRequestsMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

Web route headers: request and response

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none' ; script-src resource:; 
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
cache-control: no-cache, private
content-type: application/json
date: Wed, 18 Apr 2018 11:57:50 GMT
retry-after: 53
server: nginx/1.13.6
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImpRdGlIXC9KbnV3QTY2MkpKbEZUQ3d3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlU5YXFkZmpVXC9nMHpXSW5zK2RUZFlTVTA0N0YzaE9TeURpSHJlV0FUb1NkXC9rN3dvUUdVbzgwNHQ4MCtDU04rYjBNSHB6U2dsUzZ6cys2cGY5N1dUQVE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjAzMTRkZTdkNmEwMzk5ODZhMTQ2ODhmYTJjOWE2ODIzODQ1YzQ0OThhY2I2NWUxOTk5MDRmNDc0ZjBjMmNjMDgifQ%3D%3D; expires=Wed, 18-Apr-2018 13:57:50 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
larablog_session=eyJpdiI6IkZqaGZVUk10bFNpb2hUc2xPMXdBbVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiY0hoXC9qMHFWdENIOEZZK3BaUklhMjZtQ2JoS2IwQlRTV053clUyQVd0RmpxTlRmMlVRc1Q4QW8zYUMwZSs0dmFuM3U2N3A2ZGJCZTBaN2JwdHJDSE13PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI1YzQ0ZTNjOGI4NDI3ZDg4NTI5MDQyMDRiMTc3ODk3OGZkYjk4OWJmNzhkODFkM2UwZGU1MTM0NDdmNjIxYTY1In0%3D; expires=Wed, 18-Apr-2018 13:57:50 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
x-ratelimit-limit: 5
x-ratelimit-remaining: 0
x-ratelimit-reset: 1524052723

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkNibkJQOUM3clJscElSWGZrcDVoZGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMzJuZGljNnRzUFoxNVVOYVZscFJBRElqMHJGSGxYa2dqVXkwR0VtZlhpQUFLUkI4cHJnOFdLSGIwdEdmRnA2R2Y5WHRXZHNtTFwvUVVpc2xKM1lQVHV3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiJmNmRjMjQwMDllOWFhZGY2Y2Q2YTVmYzFjZGQxNTE4MTk3ZjRkYWUyMTA2OWY0Y2E3NGNjYTg5MmEzYTZmZjJkIn0%3D; larablog_session=eyJpdiI6IlwvUm55cHBaTVdnR21rbkJVU05DUXVBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkJlYVV3dXB6SUNjMkRrUHJ2bTN2R3RUa294aVpjelJlTVFCUENXVldpSzlKNWdYUTdqeHJtY1JEWXV5UUpvbUc0bHB4UG5hcGltTG9OSVYrdjBMS29BPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0M2ZjYWMyNjY0MjFkYTlhZjZkZmQ5MjVkMDFhODZiODFiNjQ4OGIzOTViZTNmY2E2NmNhMjQzYmRiY2I4ODdhIn0%3D
Host: project.test
Referer: https://project.test/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
```

API route headers: request and response

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none' ; script-src resource:; 
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
cache-control: no-cache, private
content-type: application/json
date: Wed, 18 Apr 2018 11:55:55 GMT
retry-after: 57
server: nginx/1.13.6
x-ratelimit-limit: 60
x-ratelimit-remaining: 55
x-ratelimit-reset: 1524052612

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InFHZVFHNDg3M2hpcG9rUHd2WnlQclE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQW1oZFZXbFc3NFhwVnpBTGZsM0tKbGlBaDhUNkM0TXpqMzZTb1FHUUI4bFk5XC9wWEdyK0lOZThyZ25vT2FLUHN2MXFZZGtuaVFta1lLdzBxZU9FdnR3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiJhMjM3MzA5ZDI1MmNjMjE0YTkyZjA4ODAyMzNmNDQwM2JjNTJjYzY4NzcyYWIwYWE5NjdmMWI0OTgwNjg5OGY4In0%3D; larablog_session=eyJpdiI6IjhTMnZTSmhMd3lSOUlLZzREd1BEN0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMVh2SFh4azM2RTJxRWFkV0g4YUxMUmRhVyt0bUVOYkZzbnZLRnBVb1gxQXB5OUQ2Y2lFZmNpMGt0NmNXSVlKSDFoWlE1aVZra2ROZEtYSzNpRzlVbGc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjhmMDNmNzgzYWViODU3NzQ0MTExMzBlNWI1OTc0MTY5YzI2ZDZkZDQ2OThmZTM3NDJjZjA4MTkxN2Y0YTVhNmQifQ%3D%3D
Host: project.test
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
```

Please advice,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The api throttle is declaring twice so the hit is count twice.

For all api route there is throttle middleware declared on **app/Http/Kernel.php**

```
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
```

To resolve the problem, you have to remove the api throttle in kernel file, and you can define separate throttle middleware group in the api route file **app/routes/api.php** as follow:

```
// limit to 60 hits in 1 min
Route::group(['middleware' => ['throttle:60,1'], 'prefix' => 'foo'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'FooController@fooMethod');
});

// limit to 500 hits in 1 min
Route::group(['middleware' => ['throttle:500,1'], 'prefix' => 'bar'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'BarController@barMethod');
});
```

Comment: I managed to change api route behavior by changing throttle in api middleware group `$middlewareGroups` to my middleware `apiThrottle`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it's working with me .

```
php artisan cache:clear
```